# Windows software to create and export imagemap

Tags: windows, image-map

I'm trying to locate software (offline) that will allow me to open an image, draw/edit multiple polygons/lines/shapes on the image (with zoom/pan controls), and then export the coordinates as text (json/xml/etc..)

Once I have an image, and it's associated image map file, I will be writing software that will read both files. My logic will draw within the boundaries specified within the coordinates of the image map, and save a new image with my specified drawing with the boundaries (be it an overlay, or text, etc..).

I've searched high and low, and all I can find are addons for larger programs, such as MATLAB or Tableau. I've found tutorials to draw coords in GIMP, but I don't see where they can be exported. I see talk about GIS/KML or SVG/Canvas, but nothing I'm doing is related to real-world maps, and while SVG appears to have what I need for my purposes (polygons, coords, etc..), I can't seem to find a tool that will do what I want. This is also somewhat related to old-school HTML image maps, but I don't actually need (or want) to output HTML, since I'd have to parse that out for my purposes.

A simple, preferably open-source, offline imagemap generator that can export the coordinates is all I need, but I can't, for the life of me find what I need. I know it exists, and I really don't want to have to write it.. Halp!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found & managed to use [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) to achieve my desired results:

I followed these tutorials:

- https://fedoramagazine.org/getting-started-inkscape-fedora/
- https://fedoramagazine.org/inkscape-creating-and-editing-paths/
- https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18088/exporting-an-object-as-svg-from-inkscape

Once I draw my desired paths/coordinates, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> allows me to "Resize the page to the drawing" (my image), and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> allows me to view the node editor and select the paths/xml I need.